# Angular 5 FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, formarray

I have this FormArray in my Angular 5 / Angular Material application:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({    
    customerNumberContainers: new FormArray([
      new FormGroup({
        contactTenant: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
        customerNumber: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])
        }),
    ]),
...
```

Actually I don't know how to run through this FormArray.
I have tried this on

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="customerNumberContainers">          
        <div *ngFor="let customerNumberContainer of form.controls['customerNumberContainers']; index as i">
            <mat-input-container class="full-width-input" style="min-width:100px;">
                 <input matInput placeholder="Tenant" formControlName="customerNumberContainer[i].contactTenant">
            </mat-input-container> 
            <mat-input-container class="full-width-input" style="min-width:100px;">
                 <input matInput placeholder="Customernumber" formControlName="customerNumberContainer[i].customerNumber">
            </mat-input-container> 
        </div>
    </div>
   ...
```

Comment: Didi you think about creating a custom component implementing ControlValueAccessor to handle the array modifications ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

actually how you should do it is like this:

have a method that return your control array

```
get customerNumberContainers(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get("customerNumberContainers") as FormArray;
    }
```

you going to use the variable *i* to manage the form groups inside your array

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div formArrayName="customerNumberContainers">          
    <div *ngFor="let customerNumberContainer of customerNumberContainers.controls; index as i" [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-input-container class="full-width-input" style="min-width:100px;">
             <input matInput placeholder="Tenant" formControlName="contactTenant">
        </mat-input-container> 
        <mat-input-container class="full-width-input" style="min-width:100px;">
             <input matInput placeholder="Customernumber" formControlName="customerNumber">
        </mat-input-container> 
    </div>
</div>
```

...

you can create add methods and delete methods to manage the formgroups inside your array

```
add(data?: any) {
   /// data is to set up values to your internal form (useful for edition)
        this.customerNumberContainers.push(this.fb.group({
         }))
    }

    remove(index: number) {
        this.customerNumberContainers.removeAt(index)
    }
```

I hope this help you

greetings

Answer (score 1):

Change your

```
<div *ngFor="let customerNumberContainer of form.controls['customerNumberContainers']; index as i">
```

To:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of getControls(); let i = index">
```

And in your .ts file add:

```
getControls() {    
 const fa = this.form.get('customerNumberContainers') as FormArray;  return 
 fa.controls; 
}
```

End result should be:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formArrayName="customerNumberContainers">          
        <div *ngFor="let item of getControls(); let i = index">
           <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <mat-input-container class="full-width-input" style="min-
               width:100px;">
                 <input matInput placeholder="Tenant" formControlName="contactTenant">
            </mat-input-container> 
            <mat-input-container class="full-width-input" style="min-width:100px;">
                 <input matInput placeholder="Customernumber" formControlName="customerNumber">
            </mat-input-container> 
        </div>
    </div>...
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You can directly use form.get('customerNumberContainers').controls in the template. the `getControls()` function is useless

Answer (score 1):

> Have a look at the working demo

[StackBlitz: Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-formarray)

> Explanation:

1. Quite a few things needs to happen to work with Form Array in Angular. Refer the [Aligator.io](https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/) blog post.
2. When used without square bracket: `formControlName="value"`, value is meant as a string.
3. When Square brackets are used: `[formControlName]="customerNumberContainer[i].contactTenant"`, then variables are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to have multiple formGroups in the form array?

```
this.form = new FormGroup({    
  customerNumberContainers: new FormArray([
    new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
    new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)])
  ])
});
```

This is how it should look if not. And remember when changing the value of a form array use a constant

```
const arr = <FormArray>this.form;
```

Then you can push, etc...

```
arr.push(new FormControl(''));
```

Some form array functions won't work if you dont.