# How to push FormGroup into FormArray?

Tags: angular

I would like to push dynamic values into a form.

```html
<div formArrayName="details">
  <div *ngFor="let detail of _detailRowNumber; index as i">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Label of a detail</mat-label>
      <input id="detail-label" matInput type="text" formControlName="label">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Description of a detail</mat-label>
      <input id="detail-description" matInput type="text" formControlName="description">
    </mat-form-field>

    <button type="button" *ngIf="_detailRowNumber.length > 1" (click)="decreaseDetailRow(detail)" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="Remove a new row from the detail list">
      <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
    </button>

    <button type="button" (click)="increaseDetailRow(i)" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="Add a new row to the detail list">
      <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
details: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    label: new FormControl(''),
    description: new FormControl('')
});

formMain = this.fb.group({
  details: this.details
});
```

So far, it works fine. So my control looks like this:

```json
details: {
  label: "my label",
  description: "my description"
}
```

But when I click on the Add button, new input fields will be added and their values I want to push to the form as well.

This is what I have tried:

```js
increaseDetailRow(index: number): void {
  this._detailRowNumber.splice(++index, 0, Date.now());
  (this.formMain.controls['details'] as FormArray).push(this.details);
}
```

But I get the error:

> this.formMain.controls.details.push is not a function

Instead of `details: this.details`, I have also tried it with `details: new FormArray([])`. but then I get this error:

> Cannot find control with path: 'details -> label'

Comment: You created your `details` as a `FormGroup`. You should create it as a `FormArray` and then push a `FormGroup` with your controls (label & description) to it. When clicking the add button, create a new FromGroup and push it to the FormArray (don't use the same instance `this.details`).

Comment: `details: new FormArray([])` is correct. The details you have (the formgroup) I'd rename detail (singular) and that's what you push a copy of onto the array. You want something like `<div *ngFor="let item of formGroup.controls.details.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">`. There's lots of examples here on stackoverflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49070042/4711754)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to get it working. I used a FormBuilder where an array of form groups was created.

**your.component.ts**

```
export class YourComponent {
  form = this.fb.array([
    new FormGroup({
      label: new FormControl(),
      description: new FormControl(),
    }),
  ]);

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  increaseDetailRow(): void {
    this.form.push(
      new FormGroup({
        label: new FormControl(),
        description: new FormControl(),
      })
    );
  }

  decreaseDetailRow() {
    this.form.controls.pop();
  }
}
```

**your.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let detail of form.controls; index as i">

  <form [formGroup]="detail">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Label of a detail</mat-label>
      <input id="detail-label" matInput type="text" formControlName="label">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Description of a detail</mat-label>
      <input id="detail-description" matInput type="text" formControlName="description">
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>

</div>

<button type="button" *ngIf="form.length >= 1" (click)="decreaseDetailRow()" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="Remove a new row from the detail list">
  <mat-icon>remove</mat-icon>
</button>

<button type="button" (click)="increaseDetailRow()" mat-fab color="primary" aria-label="Add a new row to the detail list">
  <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
</button>
```